# ORM for CodeIgniter - Relation between multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I've started a text-based browser game, using CodeIgniter.
I used Doctrine as ORM since then but I face a problem I can't seem to solve with Doctrine:
My game will have multiple servers (to limit the number of players in a single universe) and so I have multiple databases:
- One for user accounts and reference data
- One for each server with the server's specific data

Some tables from the server's databases have relations to tables from the general database. The problem is Doctrine isn't designed to handle cross database relations.
It seems there is a "fix" to make such joins:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/06/19/cross-database-joins.html

But as author says, it's just good for "edge cases". In my project, there are a lot of cross database relations, so I prefer not to use this fix.

The only solution I can figure would be to replace Doctrine with an ORM that handles well that type of relations. Does anyone know a good ORM I can use with CodeIgniter corresponding to my needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple servers that are not in the same network, the best option is to have a distributed application - each doing it's own thing and using a central server to synchronize data.

Comment: The "game servers" will be in the same network, they will actually be in the same machine. It's "game servers" not "physical network servers".
It's just the same website running on different databases schemes.